# Java int operation in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, porting

Java and Javascript produces different result when operating with large integers.

**Example:** `getCode(1747,1763,-268087281,348400)` returns `1921968083` in Java but Javascript returns `2.510115715670451e+22`.

How do I get the result in Java using Javascript?

Having done some research the problem seems to be related to **signed/unsigned 32/64 bit integer operations**. I have tried adding `|0` to the and of all operations and got `1921618368` which is closer but not identical.

**Java:**

```java
public String getCode(int intVal1, int intVal2, int intVal3, int IntA) {
    int intVal5 = intVal2 ^ intVal3  ;
    intVal5 = intVal5 + (intVal1 | IntA )  ;
    intVal5 = intVal5 * (intVal1 | intVal3  ) ;
    intVal5 = intVal5 * (intVal2 ^ IntA )  ;
    return String.valueOf(intVal5);
}
```

**Javascript:**

```js
function getCode(intVal1,intVal2,intVal3,IntA)  {
    var intVal5 = intVal2 ^ intVal3  ;
    intVal5 = intVal5 + (intVal1 | IntA )  ;
    intVal5 = intVal5 * (intVal1 | intVal3  ) ;
    intVal5 = intVal5 * (intVal2 ^ IntA )  ;
    return intVal5;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: why php? please check your tags

Comment: There are no ints in JavaScript. It might be useful to explain the algorithm rather than just dumping code on us.

Comment: Ever try `parseInt()`?

Comment: I have edited the code and included a test scenario. But basically int operations especially when involving large numbers produces different result in js & java.

Comment: Javascript doesn't separate flaoting point and integer arithmetics, therefore if you get out of the 32 bit scope, you get an overflow in java, while javascript just changes the precision and you lose the lerast significant bits. This may make a difference here. Also, most operatiosn work with flöoating point numbers in javascript, but bitwise operators only work on a 32 bit scale, which will convert the less-precises huge numbers back to integers (and may prodice overflows as well) - this is the reason why adding |0 does make a difference.

Comment: In addition to that, javascript uses IEEE 754 storage for all numbers (includeing integers), so the limits for integers are different even for those operations that use only 32 bit. (Java uses two's complement for integers)

Comment: Adding `|0` makes a difference but is still off, is it even possible to get the exact same result in Javascript?

Comment: You get the overflow at different numbers, see my second comment. It'kll get quite painfull to fully port an algorithm to javascript that may deal with numbers that are outside the 32 bit range ^^ It MAY be possible if you implemnt a class in javascript to hold the numbers and do all operations, manually producing any overflow that would occur in java.

Comment: There are [big integer libraries](http://www.joseprio.com/blog/2013/04/27/biginteger-libraries-for-js/) for javascript that may be useful, but not sure if they help with operators like `^` and `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|0` trick works well for most operations in JavaScript to simulate 32-bit ints, but **not for multiplication**. This is because multiplying two large ints can result in a number so big that it exceeds the integer precision of JavaScript's native `double` type. Once that is cast back to an int, the value is slightly wrong.

To deal with this, [`Math.imul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul) was introduced to perform true int multiplication. It's very new, so browser support naturally excludes IE. Good news though: the linked page contains a replacement function that simulates `imul` for older browsers, which works by multiplying the top and bottom halves of the numbers separately.

Here is how to fix your function. It uses `|0` after addition, and `Math.imul` for multiplication:

```javascript
function getCode(intVal1, intVal2, intVal3, IntA) {
    var intVal5 = intVal2 ^ intVal3;
    intVal5 = intVal5 + (intVal1 | IntA) | 0;
    intVal5 = Math.imul(intVal5, (intVal1 | intVal3));
    intVal5 = Math.imul(intVal5, (intVal2 ^ IntA));
    return intVal5;
}
alert(getCode(1747, 1763, -268087281, 348400));
```

The output is `1921968083`, identical to Java.